# Consuming web service in automation add-in?

Tags: c#, service, automation, web, add-in

I have programmed a web service with c# and now I would like to create a custom excel method that uses this service and reports the result to excel. The problem is that it always return the #VALUE! Error in excel.

So, how can I consume a web service in an automation addin?

Comment: And what does it return if you call it from a console application?

Comment: It returns the correct value! The service provides one hello world method that returns a string. As simple as it could get.

Comment: Have you seen the [Retrieving Web Service Data into Excel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8a40dG8zrM) video(s)?

Comment: Or [Access SOAP Web Services from Excel](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1306)?